# pylint - how do you enable all optinal checkers / extensions?

Tags: python, pylint

From this page https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/checkers/extensions.html pylint has a number of optional checkers. I pretty much just want all of them, how do I say to pylint "give me everything" without manually writing every extension out, one by one? Ideally the solution can b e passed via command-line like `--load-plugins=*`, without the need for a separate `.pylintrc` file. I've tried a number of syntaxes but pylint seems only able to recognize extensions if it exactly matches a module name.

Each of the below do not work

```
pylint --load-plugins=* foo.py
pylint --load-plugins=pylint.extensions.* foo.py
pylint --load-plugins=pylint.extensions foo.py
```

As mentioned, a hard-coded list that needs to be updated as new checkers are added over time is not a great way to keep up with the latest checks. I'd like a way to express "give me everything" that doesn't require manually changing configuration over time. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be `--enable-all-extensions` available for pylint 2.12 or more.

See `pylint --help|grep extension`:

```
  --list-extensions     List available extensions.

  --enable-all-extensions 

                        Load and enable all available extensions. Use --list-

                        extensions to see a list all available extensions.

  --extension-pkg-allow-list <pkg[,pkg]>

                        where C extensions may be loaded. Extensions are

  --extension-pkg-whitelist <pkg[,pkg]>

                        where C extensions may be loaded. Extensions are

                        extension-pkg-allow-list for backward compatibility.)
```